# jQuery/javascript adding class does not work on IE 8,9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, addclass

I have a div like this:

```
<div onclick="highlightFunction(<?php echo $id?>);">
```

I have the following js code:

```
 function highlightFunction(id) {   
    var id = "stuff" + stuff_id;
    $('#boss-stuff').find('div').removeClass('highlight-stuff');
    var stuff = $('#' + id).find('div')[0];
    var jStuff = $(stuff);
    jStuff.addClass("highlight-stuff");
 }
```

This code was place inside an onlick handle function.

The "highlight-stuff" class is just adding a background color.

I have tried various way, from javascript with document.getElementById().className to jQuery element.attr("class","stuff") etc. All work with various browsers, however IE 8 and 9 do not work. The background did not change.

Please help and thanks, I really appreciate it. If you need anything more from the code, please let me know.

Some explain: the id is unique, hence there will be no more than one element with same id. $('#boss-stuff') has a list of $('#id'). $('#id') is a li element, has div child(ren). And I want to add background color to div class.

Comment: What is `jEle`?  You didn't post where it gets its value from.

Comment: sorry It's a typo mistake. I have fixed it in the question.

Comment: Well `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` definitely work in IE.  Are you sure that the CSS for that class is not the real problem?

Comment: The CSS is pretty long, if it needed to clarify the problem, I'll try to reduce it in readable way. The code works on Chrome, Firefox, but is there still a chance of CSS being faulty that made IE 8 and 9 not work?

Comment: You say addClass and removeClass aren't working, but you haven't shown any proof of that. We don't know whether the class is failing to be added, or if the styles simply aren't being applied. Figure that out and come back to us.

Comment: @PiscesLeo there's a **much** better chance that your problem is with CSS than there is that it's with JavaScript.

Comment: @KevinB,Pointy You are right. I have looked at the css code and comment the most "suspicious" line and the highlight works fine on IE 8,9:
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 );
If it's ok could you please kindly explain why the above css line made the js code not work in the answer below so I could mark as right answer? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var jStuff = $('#' + id).find('div')[0];
jStuff.addClass("highlight-stuff");
```

Comment: I tried and it didn't work, because the jStuff is a DOM element, which would result in "has no method addClass" error, since addClass is a method of jQuery I supposed. Hence the reason for stuff being convert to jQuery object with this line jStuff = $(stuff)

Comment: maybe better would be $('#' + id + ' div:first-child')?

Comment: or `.find('div').eq(0)` to be more precise.

Comment: @Kevin Yes this does make the code looks better but still not solving my issue with the ie 8 & 9

Answer (score 0):

The fact it works in other browser and not `IE` sounds like its something silly like not including your code within the `DOM Ready` event. I remember having a issue similar to this a while ago.

You could try *(If your code is not inside the DOM ready event already)*:

**HTML**

```
<div onclick="highlightFunction(<?php echo $id?>);">
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// This is really important.. make sure all jQuery is inside the DOM ready event
$(function(){ 
    function highlightFunction(id) {   
        var id = "stuff" + stuff_id;
        $('#boss-stuff').find('div').removeClass('highlight-stuff');
        var stuff = $('#' + id).find('div')[0];
        var jStuff = $(stuff);
        jStuff.addClass("highlight-stuff");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have updated the question. As I stated in the question, the js code I put it in a onclick handle function. So how do I fixed it to make it in DOM ready event? Sorry if I'm asking silly question.

Comment: This sounds like it could the issue, remove the code from your `onclick` and copy and paste my code in the answer into your page and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your HTML hierarchy is too complex? I tried this one and addClass works to all browsers.

HTML

```
<div id="boss-stuff">
    <div id="stuffst123456">
        <div id=""class="">Div without class</div>
        <div id="" class="highlight-stuff">Div With Class</div>
        </div>
    <div id="st123457">Other Div</div>  
</div>
<input id="testBtn" type="button" value="Click Me" />
```

JavaScript

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#testBtn").click(function () {
            var id = "stuff" + "st123456";
            $('#boss-stuff').find('div').removeClass('highlight-stuff');
            var stuff = $('#' + id).find('div')[0];
            var jStuff = $(stuff);
            jStuff.addClass("highlight-stuff");
        });
    });
</script>
```

CSS

```
.highlight-stuff {
color: #ff0000;
```

}

Comment: Yes, this works. Maybe my problem is related to DOM ready event like JustAnil said? I noticed that in your test you're using a button click to fire event. Could I fire the onclick event on the div itself? However my div is a list of divs, and it dynamic so I dont know I could make it like your code. How about I set a fixed class name on all divs and it would look like this $(".fixedClassName").click(function(){}); , should this be okay?

Comment: use  $(".fixedClassName").live('click', function(){}); Note that if you want that only the selected div will be fired use .live function.

Comment: @PiscesLeo did this solution work for you? If so can you mark is as the correct answer?